# Disparity map code?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

Could someone point me to C/C++ code that can get the disparity map between a left/right stereo pair?Even matlab would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has a good piece of sample code: 
"Demo stereo matching converting L and R images into disparity and point clouds"
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp

Comment: This example now lives at: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp